# TSQL Removing last comma from concatenated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a column with concatenated values, but the string comes with a comma at the end.
How can I remove the last comma on existing values?

```
SELECT 

    m.Mais_Id
    , m.Outro

    (SELECT CAST(emp.First_Name + ' ' + emp.Last_Name + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM 
        Patos p
    LEFT JOIN 
        Employee emp
    ON
        p.Pato_Id = emp.Pato_Id
        WHERE
        m.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS Names
FROM    
    Mais m
```

I've this:

```
Mais_Id Outro Names
0       As    Adn Meas, Fjds Poi, Csa Drop,
1       Be    
2       Tee   As Been,
```

This is the pretended result:

```
Mais_Id Outro Names
0       As    Adn Meas, Fjds Poi, Csa Drop
1       Be    
2       Tee   As Been
```

Comment: Take a look to [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005), last char (,) is truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Most neat way to do this is to use `stuff()` function:

```
stuff(
    (
        select ', ' + cast(emp.First_Name + ' ' + emp.Last_Name as varchar(max)) 
        from Patos as p
            left outer join Employee as emp on p.Pato_Id = emp.Pato_Id
        where m.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
, 1, 2, '')  as Names
```

Note it's also safer to get concatenated string with `value()` function, so if you have special characters like & or < it will be properly shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Mais_id, m.Outro, Substring(newColumn, 0, LEN(newColumn) - 1)
FROM (

SELECT 

    m.Mais_Id
    , m.Outro

    (SELECT CAST(emp.First_Name + ' ' + emp.Last_Name + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as newColumn
    FROM 
        Patos p
    LEFT JOIN 
        Employee emp
    ON
        p.Pato_Id = emp.Pato_Id
        WHERE
        m.Pato_Id = p.Pato_Id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS Names
FROM    
    Mais m
)
```